# "Function name must be a string" using ganon PHP library

Tags: php, string, function

I'm using ganon PHP library to parse HTML fields. Testing in localhost with Windows, works perfectly, however when uploading on my linux hosting, returns me the following error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   form.php
>   on line 43

```
public function getAction()
{
    $html = str_get_dom($this->formHtml);

    $action = '';

    foreach($html('form') as $element) //Line 43
    {
        $action = $element->action;
        break;
    }
    return $action;
}
```

According to the documentation(https://code.google.com/p/ganon/), I'm using it correctly. This can be some checks that Linux is different from Windows? How can I solve?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? This library seems to use features that don't exist before PHP 5.3.0 (the `__invoke` magic method).

Comment: Just to clarify, that's the version on your hosting server, right? Can you check what `var_dump($form)` returns - is it an object, `NULL` or something else?  Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: Yes, 5.4 is the version on hosting and local I use 5.3. I'll post the results with var_dump and check logs when I get home.

Comment: Solved. The problem was the invoke. I change $html('form') to $html->select('form') and $element->action to $element->getAtributte('action').